# Location of Config files in Adhearsion and FreeSWITCH

Tags: ruby-on-rails, freeswitch, adhearsion

I'm getting on well, hooking up the ruby engine Adhearsion with the telephony engine FreeSwitch. However, the instructions tell me to give some config files a once over.

Specifically

```
config.punchblock.platform
```

and the permissions set on the directory

```
/var/punchblock/record
```

Could anyone please tell me where these are located?

Full instructions here:

http://adhearsion.com/docs/getting-started/freeswitch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
config.punchblock.platform
```

is in config/adhearsion.rb in your Adhearsion app.

and

```
/var/punchblock/record
```

is where asterisk is running.

[Changing file, folder permissions](http://www.westwind.com/reference/os-x/commandline/files-folders.html)

Yes, that's what I did for database connection.

```
Adhearsion.config do |config|
  config.adhearsion_activerecord do |db|
    db.username = "user"
    db.password = "password"
    db.database = "database"
    db.adapter  = "mysql"
    db.host     = "localhost"
    db.port     = 3306
  end
end

  #Centralized way to specify any Adhearsion platform or plugin configuration

  #To update a plugin configuration you can write either:
  # Option 1
      Adhearsion.config.<plugin-name> do |config|
        config.<key> = <value>
      end

  # Option 2
      Adhearsion.config do |config|
        config.<plugin-name>.<key> = <value>
      end
```

Comment: Thanks. Now, some options such as 

    config.punchblock.media_engine

simply aren't in the config file. Can I just add them myself?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not down with da kidz. What does gg mean? :P